# My googlescript is sending out duplicate emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to send out emails when an action is required in a sheet. 
However, this code is sending out duplicate emails despite setting a column for "sent" emails and adding in the condition to not send to already "sent" emails. I think the issue might be that the sheet is taking a bit longer to produce "sent" and in that time another email is sent out but I'm not sure.

```
function sendHTMLTEMP(arr,x){
var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Current Point 
 Totals");
 var column = ss.getRange('B:B');
 var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
 var x = 0;
 while (values[x][0] != "" ) {
  x++; 

if(ss.getRange(x,9).getValue() !=='' && 
  ss.getRange(x,13).getValue() 
 !== 'Sent'){
 var email = ss.getRange(x,10).getValue();
 var expert = ss.getRange(x,2).getValue();
 var manager = ss.getRange(x, 4).getValue();
 var glm = ss.getRange(x, 11).getValue();
 var warning = ss.getRange(x, 9).getValue();
 var points = ss.getRange(x,8).getValue();
 var admin = ss.getRange(x,12).getValue();
 var body = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Warning 
 Email').getContent().toString();

body = body.replace('%manager%',manager);
body = body.replace('%expert%',expert);
body = body.replace('%warning%',warning);
body = body.replace('%points%', points);
  try {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    cc: glm,
    bcc: admin,
    subject: 'Action Required on NorthEast Tracker',
    htmlBody: body
  });

 ss.getRange(x, 13).setValue('Sent')   

  } catch(err) 
  {}
 }}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: This script is sending out duplicate emails despite me attempting to prevent it. I do not want duplicate sent out. Is there anything you can spot that is causing this to happen?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information

Comment: It's probably your while statement but to be sure check your execution transcript under the view menu in the script editor.

Comment: hey utphx! what should I be checking for in the transcript?

Comment: Is it triggered from a form submit?

Comment: Hey J.G. This is triggered on change. So basically the spreadsheet that holds this script holds imported data from a master spreadsheet. Whenever a change is made the script checks whether column 9 has a new value, if it does then this script is executed and an email should be sent out to notify that an action is required. Once sent - that row on column 13 should set to "sent". But for some reason, it's sending out duplicates

Comment: in the transcript check if mailapp.sendEmail is happening twice.  You can also add Logger.log(values[x][0]) in your try statement and check logs to see if the emails are being sent twice (view menu > logs)

Comment: It does appear to be happening twice. Any suggestion on how to possibly fix this problem? I've also since changed triggers from on change to time driven to see if that might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering this email off a form submit, this is a known issue. Sometimes the form submit is triggered multiple times for only one new line on the spreadsheet. The way to fix this is a timed lock that throws out these extra submissions, a 5 second wait is usually enough to fix it.

Wrap your function in this:

```
function onSubmit(){
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
        lock.waitLock(5000); // wait 5 seconds for others' use of the code section and lock to stop and then proceed
    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b> Server Busy please try after some time <p>")
        // In case this a server side code called asynchronously you return a error code and display the appropriate message on the client side
        return "Error: Server busy try again later... Sorry :("
    }


///DO STUFF



    Utilities.sleep(3000);
    lock.releaseLock();
}
```

I'll note that it is important to error after you waitlock to actually kill the other processes, if you simply lock without that thrown error it will try to run after the first one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up - I was able to fix this issue by changing what triggered the script to run.

The container sheet was a pretty heavily used sheet which was causing the script to run every few seconds which caused duplicates to send. I've since changed the trigger to run every 30 minutes and have not seen any duplicate emails to send.

TLDR: Changed trigger from 'on change' to 'time driven - every 30 min'